# Intellij Student license and Microsoft Dream Pack license

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm a student and I can register `Intellij Student Program` for registry student license from Intellij. As in [license comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/license-matrix.jsp) here. I see that:

> Student license just for Non-commercial only, including education and
>   academic research

So if I use Intellij IDEA and write android app and publish to playstore and get earning by advertisement or by in-app billing, Do I violate license ? Or I use Intellij IDEA app and write a web application and get earning by advertisement, Do I violate license ?

I also registered `Microsoft Dreak Pack program`. I don't have any source about this program license, so can I use those application for commercial purpose ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You'll have to refer to their documentation. Dream spark I don't *think* is for non-commercial only but I haven't exactly tracked it down to be sure. The intellij seems pretty self explanatory. You're using it to make money in the end, you would not be able to do so without the app or intellij so I'd say yes it's a violation however I'm not a lawyer. I wouldn't bother with it and either buy it, as it's fairly cheap, or use Android Studio or the community version of which both are free.

Comment: I just want to know fore sure. Because if I'm a student. I can get license and I get money from my app, great. If not, I can find another solutions: buy other license (cheap enough for me) or use open source solution.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/licensing_faq.html#q10)**

> Academic licenses are only available to students and teaching staff of educational institutions. Use of a fully-functional version of IntelliJ IDEA under an academic license is restricted to **educational purposes**. For more information, see the Academic License Agreement.

**[DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Direct-EULA.aspx)**

> **No commercial use**. Except as provided below, you may not use the DreamSpark Direct Subscription software for commercial purposes or commercial software application development, publication or distribution unless you first purchase the appropriate commercial license(s) for the software.

**[Commercial Definition](http://definitions.uslegal.com/u/used-for-commercial-purposes/)**

> According to 18 USCS § 31, term "used for commercial purposes" means the carriage of persons or property for any fare, fee, rate, charge or other consideration, or directly or indirectly in connection with any business, or **other undertaking intended for profit**.

IANAL, but you can't use IntelliJ Academic License and DreamSpark Licence (there are some exceptions in the link) to build apps, if you're planning to make money with it. Adverts = money.